# Website or server at localhost

Tags: web, localhost, server

Is it possible to host a website at localhost(`127.0.0.1`)? Or maybe create a server, that displays the content of a folder on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) to setup a local webserver. The package comes with a webserver (Apache), a Database Server (MySQL), and scripting languages (PHP & Perl). It's quite popular, especially with PHP developers IIRC, and quite easy to setup and run.

Edit: Apache lets you serve websites from a local folder. If you want to list the plain content of a local folder via the webserver you can simply enable directory listing / Indexing by using .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS. If you have windows 7, you can run it on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your site by Intranet.. check your IP address and by IP address you can access your website in your intranet.